# Сгенерировать случайное существительное на английском языке и случайное существительное на русском языке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сгенерировать случайное существительное на английском языке и случайное существительное на русском языке (в транслите) используя python.
На ум приходит только модуль random, как сгенерировать случайный набор символов с ним понятно, а как реальное существительное? В идеале получить при запуске кода что то вроде:

```
stol
letter

mashina
forest
```

итд

Comment: Сами существительные есть в виде списков в интернетах, например: https://github.com/Harrix/Russian-Nouns/blob/main/dist/russian_nouns.txt Ну а дальше рандомом, да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сгенерировать слова можно с помощью фейкера. проблема только в том, что там нельзя указать часть речи желаемого результата - тут уж как бог на душу положит. Ну и в транслит самому придется переводить.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
fake1 = Faker("ru_RU")
print(fake.word())
print(fake1.word())
```

> perform
> монета

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

en = []
ru = []

with open('en.txt', 'r') as f:
    en = f.read().split('\n')
with open('ru.txt', 'r') as f:
    ru = f.read().split('\n')

for i in range(5):
    print(random.choice(en))
    print(random.choice(ru))
    print()
```

Единственный вариант, это иметь уже готовые слова на русском и на английском (можно записать их в файл) и уже выбирать из них модулем random.